# Change text height and width separately when drawing with canvas

Tags: android, text, canvas, text-size

I want to know if there is any way to modify text height and width separately when drawing with canvas. To set text size you can simply do `paint.setTextSize(x);`but it change text size in X and Y and I need to change text size in X and Y separately as you do with `paint.setTextScaleX(x);`but there isn't anything like `paint.setTextScaleY(y);`.

Is any way to implement this or does it already exists in Android ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `setTextScaleY` method, because *there is no need for one*. `setTextSize` multiplies both X and Y scale factors, and `setTextScaleX` multiplies the X scale factor only. So  you could reach any desired scaling `scaleX`, `scaleY` this way:

```
setTextSize(scaleY);
setTextScaleX(scaleX/scaleY); //setTextScaleX scales according to the CURRENT size (setTextScaleX(1) does nothing).
```

Comment: But in setTextSize I cannot put a scale 1.25 because the text is extremely small, but if I put setTextScaleX(1.25); the text is ok. I can't relate (scaleX/scaleY) because scaleY should be a number like 30 and scale X should be a number like 1.5 so it gives me a very small number and text is streched. I can't modify only X size or only Y size on this way or I am not understanding it right.

Comment: It's either you don't understand me, or I don't understand you :( What are the final scalings you want to achieve?

Comment: Nevermind I got it.
To modify only Y value I do:
setTextSize(actualTextSize*scaleFactor); setTextScaleX(actualXScale/scaleFactor);
To modify only X value I do:
setTextScaleX(actualXScale/scaleFactor);

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Yea, that's the way to use these methods.